# Why does Typescript consider [...T[], T] and [T, ...T[]] uncompatible?

Tags: typescript, types

Both types actually represent a non-empty array of `T`, but (according to typescript compiler) they are not assignable to each other ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=67&pln=2&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQTgXjgbQHRYHYFcC2ARjAE5oC6ANHHkaeQNyiSxwBCK6txJ1WG3UhUahQAYwD22AM5g4AQwBciTmgCMIkJJlzCyjqnWbtshXpWpCDOAHobcAKIkSEksoAq0eAHI23uACW0jQScvLS0gEA5tjyhAA28GAScCw%20CN4Y4lKmhErsnPLWdo7Orh5ecN4ZgcHYoQoR0bEJSSlpVX5ZIEA)):

```js
type A = [...number[], number];
type B = [number, ...number[]];

const a: A = [1];
const b: B = [1];
const ab: A = b; // Error: Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
const ba: B = a; // Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
```

Since Typescript is considered to have structural type system, it should probably treat this types as being the same, because they seem to be structurally identical. In fact, every value that is assignable to `A`, is also assignable to `B`, and vice versa, so this types should be interchangeable.

Comment: It's probably just A) an oversight, or B) costly to implement relative to the benefit of implementing it.

Comment: Out of interest, is this causing an issue in your code? It's fairly clear that we can use the type system to coerce these to the same type. I'm struggling to think of an actual problem this would cause which rearranging types wouldn't solve.

Comment: Support for [leading tuple rest elements](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) was just introduced in TypeScript 4.2. Generally speaking, the compiler cannot simply "see" that two types are equivalent because the same values are assignable to both. I assume, like @T.J.Crowder, this case was not considered; do you want an answer that says as much? In any case you should feel free to file an [issue](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) requesting it, if you can articulate a compelling use case.